# How can I add sameSite=None attribute header for all cookies in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework, cookies, woocommerce, http-headers

I have an e-commerce Ionic 5 Application connected with the WordPress website.
**I get an issue in chrome and safari browsers that block all cookies that not set the SameSite attribute.**

this is the message from chrome:
Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute
Because a cookie's SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid, it defaults to SameSite=Lax, which prevents the cookie from being sent in a cross-site request. This behavior protects user data from accidentally leaking to third parties and cross-site request forgery.

Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie:
Specify SameSite=None and Secure if the cookie should be sent in cross-site requests. This enables third-party use.
Specify SameSite=Strict or SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be sent in cross-site requests

[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEJa8.jpg)

from this issue, the application in iOS not able to (add to cart) and it always shows empty.
Any Help?